# How to Add 'Remember Me' Checkbox

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have an app where the user needs to log in and have their log in remembered but for the life of me I can't figure out why it doesn't work. I'm still new to android development and Java and I'm guessing some trivial things are completely foreign to me. If you could help me figure out why my "remember me" checkbox doesn't work that'd be appreciated.
Thank you!

**LoginActivity**

````
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.opengl.Visibility;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText email_login, password_login;
    Button button_register, button, button_regInstruktor;
    Button reg;
    CheckBox remember_me;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        email_login = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        password_login = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        button_register = findViewById(R.id.button_prijava);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button_regInstruktor = findViewById(R.id.button_regInstruktor);
        reg = findViewById(R.id.reg);
        remember_me= findViewById(R.id.zapamti_me);


        SharedPreferences spf = getSharedPreferences("checkbox", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String checkbox = spf.getString("remember", "true");

        if(checkbox.equals("true")){
            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
        else if(checkbox.equals("false")){
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Unchecked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        button_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginUser();
            }
        });

        Button btn_register_instruktor;
        btn_register_instruktor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_regInstruktor);
        btn_register_instruktor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent register_intent;
                register_intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterUserActivity.class);
                startActivity(register_intent);
            }
        });

        reg = findViewById(R.id.reg);
        reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent_reg = new Intent (LoginActivity.this, RegisterKorisnikActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent_reg);
            }
        });

    }

    private void loginUser() {
        String email = email_login.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = password_login.getText().toString().trim();

        if (email.isEmpty()){
            email_login.setError("Email is required!");
            email_login.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
            email_login.setError("Please enter valid email!");
            email_login.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(password.isEmpty()){
            password_login.setError("Password is required!");
            password_login.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(password.length()<6){
            password_login.setError("Minimal password length is 6 characters!");
            password_login.requestFocus();
            return;
        }


        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                   startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Failed to login!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });



        remember_me.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


                if(buttonView.isChecked()){
                    SharedPreferences spf = getSharedPreferences(
                            "checkbox", MODE_PRIVATE
                    );
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = spf.edit();
                    edit.putString("remember", "true");
                    edit.apply();
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "checkbox", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(!buttonView.isChecked()){
                    SharedPreferences spf = getSharedPreferences(
                            "checkbox", MODE_PRIVATE
                    );
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = spf.edit();
                    edit.putString("remember", "false");
                    edit.apply();
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "checkbox unchecked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        });






    }



}```

Also sorry for the messy code!
````

Comment: if you are new to android development learn it with kotlin. SharedPreferences has support for boolean, u don't need to store it as string "edit.putString("remember", "true");"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the app to remember your credentials after closing the app and reopening you can use **SharedPreferences**.

I did this the other day and this was my solution...

For saving the credentials you do this

```
    private void savePreferences() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Login",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    if (remLoginCredentials = true) {
        editor.putString("Uname", email.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("Pass", password.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("Rem", String.valueOf(rememberLogin.isChecked()));
        editor.apply();
    } else {
        editor.putString("Rem", String.valueOf(rememberLogin.isChecked()));
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

And to load the credentials you can do this.

```
    private void loadPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Login",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (settings.getString("Rem", null).equals("true")) {
        email.setText(settings.getString("Uname", null));
        password.setText(settings.getString("Pass", null));
        rememberLogin.setChecked(true);
        remLoginCredentials = true;
    } else {
        email.setText("");
        password.setText("");
        rememberLogin.setChecked(false);
        remLoginCredentials = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase automatically persists the user's credentials (in a secure way) and tries to restore them when the app is restarted. To pick up this authentication state, use an auth state change listener as shown in the code first fragment in the documentation on [getting the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).